# Is nginx performing a redirect before it reads my configuration?

Tags: nginx

I have a simple nginx container setup using the default nginx Docker container config, and I'm loading a React build into it. For most use cases this works perfectly, but I've encountered a quirk that doesn't work in a new app that I've been given (Which I didn't write) and I want to understand how I can fix this and why nginx is working this way.

When a client requests the address `https://example.com/abc/def.html`, they get that page because it exists. But when they request `https://example.com/abc/def`, this redirects to `http://<internal-docker-container-IP>/abc/def/`, which fails because it isn't valid from my network. I understand that the IP and port are coming from the nginx config, but I don't want to have to rewrite these for every container I deploy as that doesn't scale well.

Notably, all nginx is trying to do here is to add a trailing slash to the path, but it also rewrites the host and port. I thought I could create a rewrite rule to add the trailing slash myself, but it seems to execute too late in the process.

In debugging this, I've tried setting up a global rewrite rule to a famous web search engine. I find that this does redirect in all cases except where the URL doesn't have a trailing slash. In that case, I end up going to the container IP and get a connection timeout. This seems very strange to me. It feels as though there's a rewrite rule that is triggered before my configuration is hit, but I can't see it in the config.

Here's my `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And here's the only included *.conf file. This is as the default from the container, except I've added the rewrite on line 7:

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    rewrite ^.*$ https://www.myforcedredirectfordebugpurposes.com redirect;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

I feel as though the redirect should always trigger - after all, it's on all paths - but when I go to `https://example.com/abc/def` I end up at the failing container IP address. If I go to `https://example.com/abc/def/` (note the trailing slash) the redirect works. Isn't this weird? Is there a way to configure this to work without me having to hardcode my nginx container's address in the config? I've never had to do that before.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `try_files` directive within the root `location` block:

```
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/;
    }
```

With this extra line, incoming requests will first try the given URI, then try the URI with `.html` appended, and finally try the URI with `/` appended. It will forward the request to the first match, without showing this to the browser (So the browser doesn't need to display the forwarded address).

In the case of links that previously worked with `.html` on the end or a trailing slash, it's because these are valid uris for the web server: The `.html` files existed at those paths, and a trailing slash indicates an implicit index file because of the line `index  index.html index.htm`, so nginx returns that file from within the directory.

I'm still not sure why the URL rewriting that I tried out didn't work, but solving this hasn't been necessary to get the result I wanted, which was to avoid having to specify the server name and port within the configuration.